# Cooking marinade with chicken to use as sauce?

Tags: chicken, safety

I marinated some chicken and transferred the entire thing (pieces of chicken and all marinade) to a pan for cooking. I cooked on medium heat until the chicken was completely cooked and noticed the marinade at the center of the pan bubbling/boiling for several minutes. I poured all the marinade on the completed dish as a sauce. Some of the marinade caramelized though not all. On the other hand some of the marinade never boiled.

Could some of the marinade in the pan have been contaminated from the raw chicken and will I get food poisoning?

My reasoning is that if the pan was hot enough to cook the chicken through it should have been hot enough to cook off all the bacteria in the marinade. But I’m now reading you need to bring all of the marinade to a boil for at least 5 min in order to reuse as a sauce. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to Seasoned Advice.

From what I understood, you've boiled the marinade. That essentially means ~100C which is already above the instant pasteurization temperature. But as you must have observed some parts of the pan could have been colder and it never boiled. So without knowing the specifics about that it's hard to tell if pasteurization also happened there or not.

I would advise stirring the sauce/marinade from time to time in order to ensure even cooking/pasteurization.